# Move website to subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm working on a new version of a website and I'd like to move the files/folders of the old one to a subdirectory 'old'.  Is there a way to keep all links (css, references to "includes" folder and files, etc.) working using a redirect rule, instead of having to manually edit all php files?

Thanks!

Comment: you can do it with a subdomain, i.e. old.example.com. in this case you don't have to add a htaccess rule

Comment: Could you elaborate on that, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move all the old files to a directory `old` and then have a rewrite rule in root .htaccess like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# if file exists inside old then append /old/ in front of it
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/old/$1 -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ old/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

No, not as far as i know.

If you use phpstorm you can refactor references easily over all pages, this might fix your problem.

For future projects, it's good practice to use a variable `$absolutePath = "C:\...\"`
and save the path to the main directory in it, and use that variable in all files.

to link to an image you would do as following:

`$imagepath = $absolutepath."subdirectory\image.jpg";`

If you move your website you only have to change the one variable.
This is also something you should think about with other frequent used variables like mysql information.